# Write data frame to excel with the data frame name as filename using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several dataframes in python, say named A,B,C,D,E and want to write them to excel file named A,B,C,D,E respectively.

Below is the code I have. Reff is the table I am intending to use for reference with Reff['File'] as data frame names: A, B, C, D, E.

How do I make change to `data` to have it assigned to the data frame named Reff['File'][i]

```
for i in range(len(Reff['File'])):
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(Reff['File'][i]+".xlsx")
    data.to_excel(writer,'result')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "tables"?

Comment: @aydow Sorry, should have written dataframe. It is from a table in SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

A = pd.DataFrame()
B = pd.DataFrame()
C = pd.DataFrame()
D = pd.DataFrame()
E = pd.DataFrame()

frames = [A, B, C, D, E]
names = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

for i in range(len(frames)):
    filename = 'Filename'+ names[i] + '.xlsx'
    writer = ExcelWriter(filename)
    print(filename)
    frames[i].to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/write-excel-with-pandas/) you can use `to_excel` and `ExcelWriter`

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Pandas-Example2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks.I am assuming I need a loop for this.  I have updated  my code so far in the question. What I need to do with df to have it assigned to dataframe I want.